# Average path length of a network graph?

Tags: networking, graph, path, average, vertices

I have this network graph:

[image]

I created a distance matrix based on each vertex:

[image]

What i want to do now is to find the **"average path length"** of the network graph above, but the definition says **"the average length of shortest path between any two vertices"**. I couldn't work my head around that definition and was wondering if anyone could help me out on this.

Comment: That wording does not make a lot of sense to me either. Might it be the average length of the shortest path between any two vertices? Or is a formal definition included?

Comment: Not sure, about your definition. But the average path length is defined as the average number of steps along the shortest paths for all possible pairs of network nodes. It is a measure of the efficiency of information or mass transport on a network.

Comment: @NicoSchertler yes i think that would be a better definition.

Comment: So is your question answered by the two comments?

Comment: @NicoSchertler not really, i would need some calculations to be shown on how the average path length is calculated. The answer to the above is 1.4, but i couldn't reach that answer.

Comment: Take the average of the upper or the lower triangle of your distance matrix (excluding the diagonal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"-the shortest path between two vertices" refers to the minimum number of steps or smallest possible sum of edge weights (only 1 for this case of an unweighted graph) from a location to a destination vertex.

The average is calculated from all possible paths such as A to B and B to A, however we don't consider A to A as the graph does not illustrate any recursive paths.

Therefore to calculate the average by summing all the path values from your table and dividing by the number of paths (excluding recursive paths such as A to A).

41/30 = 1.4 (rounded from 1.36)